# PowerShell Filter on multiple parameters

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if is possible to specify multiple search filters as once. For example, I have this line of code that finds all files that have the "&" symbol.

```
get-childitem ./ -Recurse -Filter "*&*" | 
    ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName
```

I'd like to extend this so that I can search one time and find files with other symbols like %,$,@, etc. I want to find files that have any of these symbols, not neccesarly files that have all of them so I assume there needs to be an OR somewhere. I tried the below code but it didn't seem to work for me:

```
get-childitem ./ -Recurse -Filter "*&*" -Filter "%" | 
    ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-match` operator and a regex for this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
    Where { !$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.name -match '&|%|\$|@')} | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName
```

If you are on PowerShell v3 or higher you can simplify this a bit:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | 
    Where Name -match '&|%|\$|@' | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName
```

Comment: I'd use a character group (`[&%$@]`) rather than an alternation.

Comment: Yes, that would be better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have V3 or better, you can leverage the "globbing" wildcard feature:

```
get-childitem './*[&%$@]*' -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

If you've got V4, you can dispense with the $_.PSIsContainer filter and use the -Directory switch:

```
get-childitem './*[&%$@]*' -Recurse -Directory
```